# How do I extend in my class a Dom element, in mootools

Tags: javascript, oop, dom, extension-methods, mootools

I want to create a Class, say `MyDiv`, which inherits from the original DOM DIV element. 
Later in my code I would like to use it like that:

```
$('a-container').adopt(new MyDiv('my own set of params'));
```

I am missing the exact syntax to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to extend a specific Element type. If you provide a `toElement` method, you can define what'll  be *adopt*ed in such a case:

```
var MyDiv = new Class({
    initialize: function() {
        this.realDiv = new Element('div',{id:'foo'});
    },
    toElement: function() {
        return this.realDiv;
    }
});
```